# C++ data structure for an undirected graph of unknown size

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, q-learning

I'm trying to make a program that explores an undirected graph of an unknown size and builds an adjacency list as it goes. Normally I would make a `set<set<String>>` (the rooms are identified by a string) but I've been told this is unstable in C++. What would be a better data structure?

Comment: Why is stability important?  (Though I'm not sure how I'm not sure how this constitutes an adjacency-list - how do you look anything up in it?  Surely the outer structure should be a `map` or a `vector` or something that you can index into?)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to query the information later.

I can suggest two alternatives:

```
using namespace std;
set< pair<string,string> >
```

or

```
using namespace std;
multimap<string,string>
```

In the first case `set`, you can check if two nodes are connected but you need to know both nodes (A and B) to run a query. In the second case `multimap`, given node A you can easily obtain an iterator with all adjacent nodes.

You will need to insert pairs twice or use some rule like always adding edges in lexicographical order.